# Exiting and re-entering the USA after change of status to F-1

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas

I entered the USA on a B1/B2 (visitor) visa in 2014, but have changed status to an F1 (student) visa since then. I'm legally maintaining my student status by attending classes in language school (English). This is not a university program and I speak English well.

I want to stay in the US as I'm preparing for certain licensing tests in the medical field. What is the procedure to exit and re-enter? My F1 is not stamped on my passport.  Will I have to go to my home country and apply for a new F1 visa to re-enter the US?

Comment: You will need an F-1 visa. Whether you need to get it in your home country or not, I don't know. Maybe you can get it in whichever other place you want to travel to.

Comment: Have you discussed your travel plans with your DSO (designated school official)?

Answer (score 2):

If you only travel to Canada or Mexico or Caribbean islands for less than 30 days, you can re-enter as F-1 status using Automatic Revalidation and won't need an F-1 visa.

For any further travel, if you want to re-enter as F-1 status, you will need an F-1 visa. Since you don't already have an F-1 visa, you will need to apply for the visa at some US consulate. This consulate doesn't necessarily need to be in your home country -- you can try to apply for a visa at any US consulate, but the chances of success will likely be best in your home country.